# Should I add dot navigation in mega menu?

Tags: navigation, mega-menu

Should I add a dot navigation in a mega menu? Or are there other options to show a long list submenu?  [image]

Comment: If this is your actual case, then I'd much rather suggest you to organize the content. Is it really necessary to show all of them in one screen? Maybe older ones can be put under some sort of Archive

Comment: The menu item is dynamic 95% case "Dots" navigation will not appear only 5% case need to show 1 or 3 Dots max

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Do not add dot navigation.** 
The problem with this type of navigation is that user has to scan/read all data.

Instead, you can break classroom into divisions of 10. That would easy for the user to select instead of showing all data(class of 2010, class 2017 & so on) at once.

[image]

From the usability point of view, it is easy to find data instead of using dot navigation. Hope this helps let me know if you have doubts.

Answer (score 3):

### Don't do it

The purpose of having a navigation is to help the users and make it easy for them to find the required page in the website. Having overly-layered, complex or huge navigation menus defeat that very purpose.

**Instead, Restructure your navigation**

In your case, *Classrooms(should be called Classes or Batches)*, should be the only option in the menu. This should open either a list of Classes or open up the most recent Class and have a side-bar that lists out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no. You can add a standard pagination but the dots like you did are :
- not actionable
- it is very hard to understand what they are for at first glance.

You should find something else that does not have those problems.

A pagination could be enhanced with the dots like you have though, but then take care of not displaying too much redundant information.

Answer (score 2):

I think that pattern is not the best for the user, what do you think about using an input field to enter the year, and showing in small text the range of years that are available?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Armands. Too much information on the screen will most certainly lead to a higher chance of overlooking something. And overlooking something is a failure. No user likes to fail and be forced to repeat the given task.

Since in this menu you are showing classes sorted by year you can actually replace this wall of text with a more easier to navigate representation. For example a calendar should do the trick. The user will be able to pick the year (be it through an actual representation of a calendar or just the combobox with a lits of all the available classes) for the class he/she is interested in and then you can add a second layer that pops out on the screen (replaces the calendar) with the information about the class).

Comment: It is a list of alumni classrooms. Right now I have a dropdown and 80+ submenu items. So it long lists in a drop-down. a calendar also not fit here

Comment: I meant replace the "Class of ..." items with a calendar. Looking at the screenshot there is plent

Comment: I meant replace the "Class of ..." with a calendar. There is more than enough space. But even better is to just add a single combobox that - when selected triggers the showing of the detailed infor about the given class.